# What is the newest version of scribblenauts?

Tags: scribblenauts

What is the newest version of scribblenauts?
I have the oldest version and I have been looking for the newest for a month.

Answer (score -1):

The most recently released game in the Scribblenauts series was [Scribblenauts Unmasked: A DC Comics Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribblenauts_Unmasked:_A_DC_Comics_Adventure), released in September 2013.